# Solving a Set of Homogenous Linear Equations...S.B = Bdiag.S

Tags: linear-algebra, proof-verification, homogeneous-equation

I am trying to solve the following homogeneous linear equation:

$$SB = \tilde{B}S$$

where

$$
B=\left(
\begin{array}{ccc}
 \lambda  & -\lambda  & 0 \\
 0 & \lambda +\mu  & -\lambda  \\
 0 & 0 & \mu  \\
\end{array}
\right)
$$

$$
\tilde{B} = B_{diag} = \left(
\begin{array}{ccc}
 \lambda  & 0 & 0 \\
 0 & \lambda +\mu  & 0 \\
 0 & 0 & \mu  \\
\end{array}
\right)
$$

for some $S$ where $S \epsilon'$ = 1 (that is the row sums of the $S$ matrix sum to 1). Here, $S$ would be a $3 \times 3$ matrix.

**My attempt:**

I used the Mathematica command $LinearSolve[S.B, Bdiag.S]$ and then used the solution to that, but to no avail. Any help on this would be appreciated.

Here is the Mathematica code from the equations below - there was no solution.

$Solve\left[\left\{\mu  s_{12}-\lambda  s_{11}=0,
                          s_{13} (\mu -\lambda )-\lambda  s_{12}=0,
                          \mu  s_{21}=0,\lambda  s_{21}=0,
                          \lambda  \left(s_{22}+s_{23}\right)=0,
                           s_{31} (\lambda -\mu )=0,\lambda  \left(s_{32} s_{31}\right)=0,
\lambda  s_{32}=0,s_{11}+s_{12}+s_{13}=1,s_{21}+s_{22}+s_{23}=1,s_{31}+s_{32}+s_{33}=1\right\},\left\{s_{11},s_{12},s_{13},s_{21},s_{22},s_{23},s_{31},s_{32},s_{33}\right\}\right]$

Comment: Are $\lambda$ or $\mu$ positive? Are either of them zero?

Comment: Yes, both $\lambda$, $\mu$ > 0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order for this system to have a solution the following set of equations must be satisfied:

\begin{align}
\mu s_{12} - \lambda s_{11} &= 0\\
(\mu - \lambda)s_{13} - \lambda s_{12} &= 0\\
\mu s_{21} &= 0\\
\lambda s_{21} &= 0\\
\lambda (s_{22} + s_{23}) &= 0\\
(\lambda - \mu)s_{31} &= 0\\
\lambda(s_{32}-s_{31}) &= 0\\
\lambda s_{32} &= 0\\
s_{11} + s_{12} + s_{13} &= 1\\
s_{21} + s_{22} + s_{23} &= 1\\
s_{31} + s_{32} + s_{33} &= 1
\end{align}

If both $\lambda \neq 0$ and $\mu \neq 0$, then it is not possible to satisfy these equations since you would have $s_{21} = 0$ and $s_{22} + s_{23} = 0$, in which case $s_{21} + s_{22} + s_{23}$ clearly cannot sum to $1$.

Comment: Is there a solution? How  can you put that in matrix form

Comment: I don't believe so.

Comment: I put it in Mathematica...see results above...it gives no solution

Comment: Right, because the system you are trying to solve does not have a solution.

Comment: That explains it then - How did you get those equations above?

Comment: By equating the matrices $SB$ and $\tilde{B}S$ you get up to nine equations involving the coefficents of $S$. I dropped the first such equation since it holds vacuously. The last three equations are just the row sum constraints.

Comment: Need to work it out and digest this - Thanks so much!